# NextJS, Clerk - Organisation won't apply on user

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, clerk

I'm using Clerk to do user auth for my app's back office and i applied an organization on a user with the admin role on Clerk's dashboard. However when inside the Clerk middleware and trying to access user infos it shows the user but the orgId is undefined.

First, i applied org to user on Clerk dashboard :
[image]
[image]

Tried console.log the user infos with the auth() method provided in the afterAuth option :

```js
import { authMiddleware, redirectToSignUp } from "@clerk/nextjs";

export default authMiddleware({
    afterAuth(auth, req, evt) {
        console.log(auth)

    },
    publicRoutes: [
        "/api/albums/all",
        "/",
        "/player/(.*)",
        "/login"
    ],
});

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
};
```

This is the console.log result :

```js
{
  actor: undefined,
  sessionClaims: {
  azp: 'http://localhost:3000',
  exp: 1698860167,
  iat: 1698860107,
  iss: 'https://able-pelican-18.clerk.accounts.dev',
  nbf: 1698860097,
  sid: 'sess_2XaGCNVMHEqLEujCfqDe88xxVo7',
  sub: 'user_2XaG41***********RM8'
},
  sessionId: 'sess_2XaGCNVMHEqLEujCfqDe88xxVo7',
  session: undefined,
  userId: 'user_2XaG41***********RM8',
  user: undefined,
  orgId: undefined,
  orgRole: undefined,
  orgSlug: undefined,
  organization: undefined,
  getToken: [Function],
  debug: [Function],
  isPublicRoute: true,
  isApiRoute: true
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Same here, ideally the org creator should be the member of that org right? I think to avoid making a decision of default org between multiple orgs they've made it as undefined and provided a client component to switch.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the user, after logging in to your application, won't have a predefined org. To switch to a specific organization, you could use the [Organization Switcher](https://clerk.com/docs/components/organization/organization-switcher) in the UI of your application, and if you want to handle the organization switcher directly with your code, you can use the [setActive](https://clerk.com/docs/references/react/use-organization-list#returns) function of this hook. I haven't found a way to set up an organization automatically using backend code.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was using the [Organization Switcher](https://clerk.com/docs/components/organization/organization-switcher) component.

I logged in with the user Admin in the Organization and switched to the organization that I want. Once this happened I was getting a response with the actual information of the Organization.

```
Auth Response: {
  actor: undefined,
  sessionClaims: {
  azp: 'http://localhost:3000',
  exp: 010101010101,
  iat: 010101010101,
  iss: 'https://mature-tapir-22.clerk.accounts.dev',
  nbf: 1701000000,
  sid: 'sess_2YvT2s....',
  sub: 'user_2YrWTn....'
},
  sessionId: 'sess_2YvT2s....',
  session: undefined,
  userId: 'user_2YrWTn.....',
  user: undefined,
  orgId: 'org_2Yrc.....',
  orgRole: 'admin',
  orgSlug: 'rhiz',
  organization: undefined,
  getToken: [Function],
  debug: [Function],
  isPublicRoute: true,
  isApiRoute: true
}
```

This is how I configured my afterAuth inside the authMiddleware

```
    afterAuth(auth, req:NextRequest, evt) {
    console.log('Auth Response:', auth);
    if(req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/admin')){

        if(!(auth.orgRole === 'admin')){
            const redirectUrl = `${req.nextUrl.origin}/`;
            return NextResponse.redirect(redirectUrl);
        } else {
            console.log('AUTH.ORG.SLUG:', auth.orgRole);

        }
    }
```

I hope this helps you.
I was surprised this step of switching the organization was not in Clerk's documentation.

It is a important step in order to have some kind of Role based auth.

Comment: Whats the point of redirecting to the origin? As a admin i should be member of the org that I've created right?

Comment: To redirect to localhost:3000, when I tried redirecting only to '/' I had problems so using the origin from the req solved that. 

You technically are part of the org ( admin or member ) but you have to switch the organization manually, that's why I used the Organization Switcher component.

Answer (score 0):

`orgId` only gives active Organization (Refer: https://clerk.com/docs/references/nextjs/authentication-object#authentication-object), but until unless we use  we cannot set the active org. So to have this from the backend code we can use [Clerk Node.js SDK](https://clerk.com/docs/references/nodejs/overview#install-clerk-node-js) and get org list of the user (either admin or a member) of the specified clerk account. One use-case is using the org list we can decide whether to redirect to `/onboarding` or to the `/dashboard` without client code (on route.ts for Next.js apps).

No configuration is required for this, one single ENV variable as specified in [[1](https://clerk.com/docs/references/nodejs/overview#install-clerk-node-js)].

Sample output:

```
[
  _OrganizationMembership {
    id: 'orgmem_2YqOBEos2USIkjhgtjfQwBb5KsoZ',
    role: 'admin',
    publicMetadata: {},
    privateMetadata: {},
    createdAt: 1701249505835,
    updatedAt: 1701249505835,
    organization: _Organization {
      id: 'org_2YqOBFR9fAnMNyykAddjGPrZerJ',
      name: "Swaroop's Org",
      slug: 'afia-pro',
      imageUrl: 'https://img.clerk.com/eyJ0eXBlIjoiZGVmYXVsdCIsImlpZCI6Imluc18yWUFtNm9LMEM3Nm1LWFhJbjZPbk1rYzUxUHIiLCJyaWQiOiJvcmdfMllxT0JGUjlmQW5NTnl5a0FFZWpHUHJaZXJKIiwiaW5pdGlhbHMiOiJTIn0',
      hasImage: false,
      createdBy: 'user_2YlHzwOltj24hUxYFh6jTWowX3Z',
      createdAt: 1701249505821,
      updatedAt: 1701249505821,
      publicMetadata: {},
      privateMetadata: [Object],
      maxAllowedMemberships: 3,
      adminDeleteEnabled: true,
      members_count: undefined
    },
    publicUserData: _OrganizationMembershipPublicUserData {
      identifier: 'zyzylafy@afia.pro',
      firstName: 'zyzylafy',
      lastName: 'afia',
      imageUrl: 'https://img.clerk.com/eyJ0eXBlIjoiZGVmYXVsdCIsImlpZCI6Imluc18yWUFtNm9LMEM3Nm1LWFhJbjZPbk1rYzUxUHIiLCJyaWQiOiJ1c2VyXzJZbEh6d09sdGoyNGhVeFlGaDZqVFdvd1gzWiIsImluaXRpYWxzIjoiWkEifQ',
      hasImage: false,
      userId: 'user_2YlHzwOltj24hUxYFh6jTWowX3Z'
    }
  }
]
```

In my case I did this inside `route.ts` (this can be done in `afterAuth` function in middleware.ts):

```
import Clerk from "@clerk/clerk-sdk-node"
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs"
import { redirect } from "next/navigation"
import { NextRequest } from "next/server"

export async function GET(_request: NextRequest) {
  const { userId, orgId } = auth()

  if (userId) {
    const orgList = await Clerk.users.getOrganizationMembershipList({
      userId: userId ?? "",
    })

    if (orgList.length === 0) return redirect("/onboarding")
  }

  return redirect("/directory/supplier")
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: @webcu This might be what you are looking for to set active organization by passing orgId as props to client/page

Answer (score 0):

I found the Clerk's guide [Hide Personal Accounts and force organizations](https://clerk.com/docs/guides/force-organizations) very helpful.

The guide says:

> *Setting an active organization can only be performed client-side.*

Thus they give you several ways to set the active organization on the client (1 automatic approach as well). And once you have the active org then you can use the `authMiddleware` to restrict the access only to the users having an organization.